# How to make 161 meter / 528ft circles on with OSMDROID?

Tags: geometry, osmdroid, markers

I'm using OsmDroid on OpenStreetMaps and can make markers and polylines, but I can't find any examples on how I'd make 161m/528ft circles around a marker.

a) How do I make circles?
b) How do I make them 161m/528ft in size?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to MKer, I got an idea on how to solve the problem and made this piece of code, which works:

```
oPolygon = new org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Polygon(this);
final double radius = 161;
ArrayList<GeoPoint> circlePoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
for (float f = 0; f < 360; f += 1){
    circlePoints.add(new GeoPoint(latitude , longitude ).destinationPoint(radius, f));
}
oPolygon.setPoints(circlePoints);
oMap.getOverlays().add(oPolygon);`
```

I know this can be optimized. I'm drawing 360 points, no matter what the zoom is!

[image: Black 161meter circle made with Omsdroid on OpenStreetMap]

Comment: Excellent idea. I made some trials, the better value for the step seems to be 6 degrees (from 10 degrees, segments are visible). As this question came regularly, I added the feature directly in the OSMBonusPack Polygon class: this is the setPointsAsCircle method, now commited.

Comment: Oh no, now I need to update my code to use the new method setPointsAsCircle :-) (just kidding) Actually I decided to use 6 degrees in my code as well :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a "graphical" circle, then you can implement easily your own CircleOverlay, using the [DirectedLocationOverlay](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/DirectedLocationOverlay.java) as a very good starting point.

If you want a "geographical" circle (than will appear more or less as an ellipse), then you can use the OSMBonusPack Polygon, that you will define with this array of GeoPoints:

```
ArrayList<GeoPoint> circlePoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
iSteps = (radius * 40000)^2;
fStepSize = M_2_PI/iSteps;
for (double f = 0; f < M_2_PI; f += fStepSize){
  circlePoints.add(new GeoPoint(centerLat + radius*sin(f), centerLon + radius*cos(f)));
}
```

(warning: I translated from a [Nominatim](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/blob/master/lib/Geocode.php) piece of code in PHP, without testing)

Comment: Thanks MKer. There is something wrong with the matematics iSteps became extreme big when I enter radius=161 m, but it got me in the right direction. So I found another way of doing it. I notived that i could use Geopoint.destinationPoint(radiusInMeter, fInDegrees) and then turn 360 degrees. Now I only need to uptimze the steps in the 360 degrees.

Comment: Are you sure `M_2_PI` is what you think it is? `M_2_PI` isn't 2π; it's 2/π.

Comment: @flarn2006 The code for osmdroid "Polygon.pointsAsCircle" has changed since my initial suggestion above. Test is "f < 360" (no M_2_PI).